# How can I get `grantedScopes` through `getLoginStatus` from Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

According to the documentation, I can get `grantedScopes` using the method of [FB.login()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.7#params). But if the user is already logged in, how can I get it?

I can call `FB.getLoginStatus()`, but this method does not return the required scope. Why is so and how do I get a scope from client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do an API call to the `/me/permissions` endpoint:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Example result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_likes",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_posts",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```